# How to store image in database?

Tags: android

I am working on an application which needs to store image in database. I have tried it by converting image into bytes but it is very slow process.is there any other way to store image in database

Comment: I'd recommend storing the image normally, and then just referecing the file name and location in the database.

Comment: I don't know how androids work, but can you not just store the image name in the DB, and the image in some sort of directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store image path into database and store images in sdcard and retrieve images from imagepath from database

Answer (score 1):

Get image form sd card

```
if (requestCode == SD_REQUEST) {
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();

Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

testimage.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
yourSelectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
}
```

Save Image

```
DatabaseAdapter dbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(Profiles.this);

   dbHelper.open();
   dbHelper.createUserProfiles( byteArray);
   dbHelper.close();
```

NOw in DatabaseAdapter.java

Define

```
public static final String U_PIC = "picture";
```

Then

```
private long createUserTableContentValues(long id,byte[] byteImage) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ID, id);
        values.put(U_PIC, byteImage);
return database.insert(IMAGE_INSERT, null, values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store image path in database in string format..